# Microsoft Flow weekly remainder

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

I want to create a flow that checks which files have been added without being filled with the appropriate Metadata.

The flow checks that and then sends an email once a week to the creater letting them know that these files have no Metadata

Can anyone help me achieve this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is short version:

1. Create Flow with Recurrence
   [image]
2. Get Files from Library (if there will be more libraries, there should be more these functions.
   I selected my test site and default *Documents* library. I also filtered documents only for new (created 7 days ago and newer) **You can change this.**

   - Created gt '@{getPastTime(7, 'Day', 'o' )}'
     [image]
3. Add foreach loop - In foreach loop will be **Condition (IF) for your selected METADATA which should NOT be EMPTY** and into TRUE statement will be SEND email to *Created email* (everything on screenshots)
   [image]
4. I tested with empty Title on new Document (only this document was get with Flow, because my filter)
   [image]
   [image]

Done in 15 minutes.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: thanks a lot. I marked it as solved. What would happen if more than one file was missing the metadata ?  Will the email consist of mutiple links then ?

Comment: Yes it will get all files with missing metadata. No, email is per one document. If you want multiple links per Author, it will be a little difficult. But this is the base scenario. You can alse change first filter to your columns eq '' and it return all files with empty metadata values directly and no IF will be needed.

Comment: how would I go if I would want mutiple links per author. Can you help me with that ?